# dBeaver Community - SQL Editor in Unicode instead of ASCII

Tags: dbeaver

I loaded a SQL script file which contains Chinese and other international characters in the strings into dBeaver community editor.
All these Chinese and other international characters in the SQL script file are loaded as some sort of ASCII characters.
For example, "值班）杂项" is loaded as "ï¼ˆå€¼ç�­ï¼‰æ�‚é¡¹".
I can see these characters correctly in NotePad++ or other text editors.

How can I change dBeaver SQL editor setting to use Unicode character set instead of ASCII character set?